# Automator script to do a whois lookup

Tags: macos, automator, whois

I'd like to take an IP address from my Terminal, right click, select Services > Whois and get the results back somehow.

This doesn't exist so I'm wanting to create a simple Automator script to do that. But, I'm running into a few problems.

This is what I've done - Automator Actions:

**Get Specified Text**

`xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`

**Run Shell Script**

```
for x in "$@";
do whois $x; 
done
```

**View Results**

But all I get in View Results is this:

```
(
  ""
)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to pass the input to the shell script *as arguments* and not to STDIN:

[image]

For showing the results, you could drag *Run AppleScript* to the bottom of the pane and use the following commands:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set msg to ""
    repeat with itm in input
        set msg to msg & "
" & itm
    end repeat
    tell application "Finder"
        display alert "Whois" message msg
    end tell
end run
```

Comment: Awesome answer. Works fine in Automator but I get an error when I run it through the right click menu: 'The action "Run AppleScript" encountered an error.'

Comment: @SnowCrash Updated the script.